# How do I find out where Windows 10 messages are sent from?

Tags: windows-10

I have a message that occasionally shows up after I log in:

> Remote Connection
>   Could not connect to 127.0.0.1!

[image: Screenshot]

There does not appear to be anything related to it in Event Viewer; but since this usually occurs at login, there are a lot of events to look through.

Usually, if this shows up, it is if I wake the PC from sleep.

What is a good way to trap where this is coming from? Is there a way?

Comment: Do you use any kind of program to manage PC's remotely like Teamviewer? Do you have any remote desktop connections active? Are you using VPN? Maybe check out Task Scheduler and see if anything is set to run on logon.

Comment: when the message is gone, you see an entry in action center with the name of the program which raised the toast message

Comment: @Bungicasse: I do have a remote VPN for work. I do not work from home often though (only once, to date). Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: @magicandre1981, there is no message visible in the Action Center after the notification shows.

Comment: have you missed the toast? closing the toast by yourself doesn't show it in action center

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I think I click the message (toast?) every time, trying to get it to display any kind of dialog. I'll try letting it time out, and see if something shows up in the Action Center.

Comment: ok, don't interact with it. Let it timeout and go away. now open action center